# Checking duplicates with divide and conquer

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

To search duplicates in nlogn I decided to use a merge sort modified.
The main problem is that an error appear and I don't know how to fix this problem: Results sometimes are completely wrong.

My algorithm has to return True if it found a pair( an element with the same value) or False if it has not a pair. All this must be done inside the divide and conquer algorithm.(no extra for loop ecc.)

This is the code

```
def check_duplicates(X):   
    if len(X)>1:
        mid = len(X)//2
        lefthalf = X[:mid]
        righthalf = X[mid:]

        check_duplicates(lefthalf)
        check_duplicates(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i<len(lefthalf) and j<len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] == righthalf[j]:
                return True

            if lefthalf[i]<righthalf[j]:
                X[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                X[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i<len(lefthalf):
            X[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j<len(righthalf):
            X[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1

   return False
```

Let's make some examples:
let `X=[1,2,3]` the function returns `false`, it's ok.
let `X=[1,3,2]` the function returns `false`, which is also ok.

The main problem are with this cases:

let `X=[1,3,3]` the function returns `false`, which is wrong(should return true).

let `X=[4,6,6]` the function returns `false`, which is wrong and so on.

The main problem is when I put two same values at the end of the list, and I have no idea how to fix it...

ps: i apologise for my english

Comment: So, basically this is a merge sort which also checks whether there's a duplicate in the merge part?

Comment: Yes... but there are problems when two same values are at the end of the list..

Comment: If [these numbers](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt) are correct, I think you can do it in O(N) using `len(set(X)) != len(X)`

Comment: @Matt we can not use sets... just Arrays and basics operations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot that if you do the recursive call, and the call results in `True`, to return `True` as well: thus, modify the recursive call to:

```
if(check_duplicates(lefthalf)) :
    return True
```

Or the full (indented) version reads:

```
def check_duplicates(X):   
    if len(X)>1:
        mid = len(X)//2
        lefthalf = X[:mid]
        righthalf = X[mid:]
        if(check_duplicates(lefthalf)) :
            return True
        if(check_duplicates(righthalf)) :
            return True
        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i<len(lefthalf) and j<len(righthalf) :
            if lefthalf[i] == righthalf[j]:
                return True
            if lefthalf[i]<righthalf[j]:
                X[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                X[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i<len(lefthalf):
            X[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j<len(righthalf):
            X[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1

    return False
```

In the while loop, you only check for cross-equality (equal elements in the two sublists). But the result in your version is only returned if it `return True`s on the top level comparison.

You in other words forgot to propagate the `True` value in the call stack.

Comment: Thanks for the help, anyway with your code, it always return True because since the merge sort is recursive, it will always call `check_duplicates(lefthalf)` or `check_duplicates(righthalf)`. I have tried with `X = [1,4]` and it returned True, which is wrong. Any idea?

Comment: @BioShock: I've tested it with and it returns `False`, Make sure you preserve indentation. It won't always return `True`. Lists with one element for instance return always `False`.